# Liquibase Command Line: How to use Oracle connection string instead of JDBC database url

Tags: oracle, jdbc, liquibase

Can I use an Oracle connection string instead of a JDBC database url to connect the Liquibase Command Line tool to my Oracle database?

Comment: What exactly is an "Oracle connection string"? To me a JDBC url **is** an "Oracle connection string"

Comment: dbForge Studio Express for Oracle 32-bit displays in its Properties window for a given database a property named `Connection String` whose value is something like `User Id=ME_F00;Server=MYSERVER;Unicode=True;Connection Timeout=0`.

Comment: Yep - JDBC and ODBC both have similar concepts (a string that groups together the information needed to connect to a database), but they are not equivalent. ODBC went with a more 'wordy' string of key=value pairs with semicolons, JDBC went with a URL, where the format of the URL is defined by the database vendor.

Answer (score 1):

No, because Liquibase uses only the JDBC drivers and not ODBC.